# Sorting in MySQL in a specific manner in one column

Tags: mysql, columnsorting

So I have a data where one of the column (section) contains the following:
A1LB
A1LC
A1RC
A2LB
A2LC
A2RC
B1LB
B1LC

but I want the data to look like this:
A1LC
A1LB
A1RC
A2LC
A2LB
A2RC
B1LC
B1LB

I have tried "ORDER BY CASE WHEN section like %LC" THEN 1 else 2 END"
but it comes out with all of the LCs on top
A1LC
A2LC
B1LC
B2LC
A1LB
A1RC
A2LB
A2RC
B1LB
B1RC

how can I do so without having all of the LC's on top but in the order I want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like:

```
ORDER BY substring(section, 1, 3), substring(section, 4, 1) desc
```

Comment: I used the substring(section,1,3) but I couldn't use substring(section,4,1) desc because I had other classes that didn't fit in that criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sorting like this

1. Sort by the first 2 characters
2. Then list records having the last 2 characters of `LC`
3. Then sort by the last 2 characters in general

```
 ORDER BY substring(section, 1, 2), 
          substring(section, 3, 2)  'LC',
          substring(section, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a table mapping {LC -> 1, LB -> 2, RC -> 3}. You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE map (ky VARCHAR(2), ord TINYINT, PRIMARY KEY(ky,ord))

INSERT INTO map VALUES ('LC', 1), ('LB', 2), ('RC', 3)

SELECT col
FROM table 
JOIN map ON RIGHT(col, 2) = map.ky
ORDER BY LEFT(col, 2) ASC, map.ord DESC
```